how to properly upload files via curl in php
I have the following curl command  from
link source
curl -sSLX POST 'https://file-scan.aws.us.pangea.cloud/v1/scan' \
-H 'Authorization: Bearer my-token-goes here' \
-H 'Content-Type: multipart/form-data' \
-F 'request={"transfer_method":"multipart"};type=application/json' \
-F 'upload=@AnnBall.png;type=application/octet-stream'

Now I need to write the curl in PHP to enable be upload files as per code below
<?php
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://file-scan.aws.us.pangea.cloud/v1/scan');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'POST');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, [
    'Authorization: Bearer my-token-goes-here',
    'Content-Type: multipart/form-data',
]);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, [
    'request' => '{"transfer_method":"multipart"}',
    'upload' => new CURLFile('AnnBall.png', 'application/octet-stream'),
]);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);

echo $response = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);

?>

Here is the error I got

{"request_id":"prq_nxj6w7ws5ussjsniphkzk7i3pqlf5peu","request_time":"2024-04-25T17:15:00.638627Z","response_time":"2024-04-25T17:15:01.722276Z","status":"InvalidBodyError","summary":"Failed to read request body","result":null}

can someone help me fix the issue

You can use https://incarnate.github.io/curl-to-php/ to convert to PHP. It's kind of old, it still uses @filename instead of new CURLFile(), but it should work.

I tink this tells it: RAW POST using cURL in PHP

Here are some possible issues with your code:

When using multipart/form-data, ensure to pass a string for the CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS option instead of an array. PHP will automatically encode an array into a multipart/form-data format if you pass an array, but it won't handle nested data properly in this case. Therefore, you need to manually construct the multipart body.

Please ensure that the file path AnnBall.png is correct and accessible from your PHP script.


Here's the working code you can try out:
<?php

// Endpoint URL
$url = 'https://file-scan.aws.us.pangea.cloud/v1/scan';

// Request headers
$headers = [
    'Authorization: Bearer YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN', // Replace YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN with your actual token
    'Content-Type: multipart/form-data'
];

// Request data
$data = [
    'request' => json_encode(["transfer_method" => "multipart"]),
    'upload' => new CURLFile('AnnBall.png', 'application/octet-stream', 'upload')
];

// Initialize cURL session
$ch = curl_init();

// Set cURL options
curl_setopt_array($ch, [
    CURLOPT_URL => $url,
    CURLOPT_POST => true,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $data,
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => $headers,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false, // Note: set to true in production for better security
]);

// Execute the request
$response = curl_exec($ch);

// Check for errors
if ($response === false) {
    echo 'cURL error: ' . curl_error($ch);
}

// Close cURL session
curl_close($ch);

// Output response
echo $response;

?>

Here's a simple explanation of the above code:
I'm using the curl_setopt_array function to set multiple options at once, and I'm also using the curl_file_create function to manage file uploads.
Note:
Replace YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN with your actual token.
